# My datagridview cellvalue changed event is not working ..C# & SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

There is small bug in my code. My datagridview cell value changed event is not working. When I add any data, rows to the datagrid view is should display the total amount to the textbox which is not working. Can you help me please?

Code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        txtNetAmt.Text = CellSum().ToString();

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    }

    txtNetAmt.Text = sum.ToString();
    int DiscountedSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        DiscountedSum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    }

    txtDiscamt.Text = DiscountedSum.ToString();
    int SubTotal = sum + DiscountedSum;
    txtSubTotalamt.Text = SubTotal.ToString();
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: But you can set breakpoint and tell us at which point you are getting error?

Comment: actually i am not getting any error.Just a case that  It is not displaying values in the text boxes which supposed to display. I am beginner .

Comment: Are you getting value of SubTotal.ToString() value in your code try to check it in add watch.

Comment: Yes I am getting value of SubTotal.ToString() sir. actually this same code works as it is on button click event. But  i want it to work on cellvalue changed event.

Comment: your image shows DiscAmt as column 4 and TotalAmt as column 5 but your code uses indexes 4 and 5, should these be 3 and 4 since indexing the Cells in the row uses the index of the column and not the position?
`sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
DiscountedSum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);`

Comment: there is one more column at position 0 sr no which is hidden.

Comment: @Vaibhav you're going to have to debug the program yourself by putting a break point in your method or provide some other information to help. I have not been able to recreate the bug with the provided information.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have event binding declared as shown below:

C# code:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new 
DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
```

Comment: Where should i declare it ?

Comment: this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);

Comment: this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);  this line is there on form.designer.cs